# Grizzly server - works with IP, but not with domain name

Tags: windows-7

I'm hosting a [grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) web service on a Windows 7 Pro machine (embedded in a regular Java process), and it is binding to `http://my-domain-name`.

When trying to hit the service from another machine, requests to `http://my-domain-name` fail (fiddler shows error code 502), but requests to `http://my-ip` work. When the service runs on a Windows Server 2008 machine, this doesn't happen (both requests succeed).

What could be the issue?

Comment: How's your name resolution set up for `my-domain-name`?

Comment: We have a local dns

Comment: Please provide more detail.  What kind of record is set up for that name, what address is it pointing to?  Are the non-functional clients using that name server for resolution?  What zone is the record in, and is the DNS search suffix consistent between working and non-working clients?  Is the name the same name as the computer's NetBIOS name?

Comment: Pinging "my-domain-name" resolves to "my-ip". It's a pretty standard gig, I think. All the machines use the same name server. Also, there is no such thing as 'non-functional' client. The same client works fine when the server is a Windows2k8 machine, which leads me to believe this is a server and not a client problem (also, WCF hosted services seem to work fine in all machines). And yes, the name is the same as the NetBIOS name, plus our local dns suffix

Comment: By "non-working client" I mean the system that you're referring to here: `When trying to hit the service from another machine, requests to http://my-domain-name fail`